# iframe scrollbar replace with my own design

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, scrollbar

I would like to set custom image to my iframe scrollbar. I know that there are some extensions or add-ons that can be used, but I didnt find a way o customize the design of them. I have png images of my custom scroll bar and I would like to replace the default design with my own. Is it possible? If so how? Can you point me to some direction?

Thank you

Comment: As a user... unless you have a very niche game site where the theme is extremely important I would likely find it really annoying if you changed the scrollbars (color/style/images) on me.

Comment: But the default design of iframe scrollbar is not corresponding with the background. So can you suggest something?

Comment: Easiest way is to make sure your target audience is using IE6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [good resource](http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/) that I used to get it working in Webkit browsers:

But the bigger issue is the iFrame.  If you own the content in the iFrame or can change the CSS in it then you are good to go.  If you don't own stuff within the iFrame and are using the iFrame to pull in a page from another site then you won't be able to change the scrollbar from the original page.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, I can set background image and other properties to those elements. And yes, I own the content of that iframe. Should I do these settings in css file, which is related to the iframe or to the html, where the iframe shows?

Comment: You'll have to do it in the CSS within the iFrame.

Comment: just to make sure :) ... right in html inside <style></style>, or it is fine to include a css file in that iframe html file, or this doesnt reallz matter?

Comment: Anything within that iFrame is a complete HTML file.  So you are free to put it in a CSS Linked file, or in the header.  It's your call.  (I would recommend best practice of linking in an external CSS file, but it really is up to you).  If this has answered your question be sure to mark it as the answer so that others can easily find the answer when searching.

Comment: thank you, I will accept your answer, it worked. But am I right that this will not work in IE?

Comment: This solution will only work in certain browsers as it is a CSS only solution and only some browsers allow this.  You'll have to play around with it in different browsers and do some searching for solutions for those browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [NiceScroll](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/) jQuery widget.

It supports IE6+, Chrome 2+, Firefox 3+, Opera 9.5+ and Safari 4+ (and modern mobile browsers), it has a lot of features and it's easy to customize.

Also, it's pretty easy to use. You just call .niceScroll() on the object you want to have a "nicer" scrollbar (in case of an iframe, you will use it on the $("html") object inside it).